# How can i view all the users that have check-in a place on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Donut-House/1420611911503923

In the above link it is showing 1450+ users that have check-in this place (i.e., "1,450 people have been here"). But, when i click and open the list there are only 400 users only. Why? And how can i view all the users?

Comment: You can't. Most likely it is privacy that decide if you can see them or not

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You are not able to view every single user because not everyone makes their Facebook posts public.